# Create list of distinct values across multiple tables

Tags: excel, distinct, names

I have made a excel document containing information on the last 2 years of sports. This includes multiple tables across multiple sheets named 'Running', 'Cycling', 'Power', etc.

For each sport I like to keep track of who I trained with, sometimes only mentioning one name, and sometimes two, separated with a comma (e.g. 'John Doe, Jane Doe').

I would like to summarize all names across all tables, and how many times each name is mentioned (how many times I've sported with them.

I have tried to use this formula:

```
INDEX(Running[With],MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Running[With])+(Running[With]=""),0))
```

but that does not work well across different sheets and does not separate comma separated names.

Comment: I'd misunderstood the question, and have now updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**.

Then you can write code like the following:

```vb
Dim dict As New Dictionary
dict.CompareMode = TextCompare ' Uniqueness of names will be case-insensitive:
                               ' John Doe is equivalent to jOhN dOe

Dim sheets() As Worksheet
sheets = Array(Worksheets("Running"), Worksheets("Cycling"), Worksheets("Power"))

Dim sheet As Variant
For Each sheet In sheets
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In sheet.UsedRange.Cells
        Dim substrings() As String
        substrings = Split(cell.Value, ",") ' split cell contents on the commas
    
        Dim substring As Variant
        For Each substring In substrings
            substring = Trim(substring) ' remove spaces before and after substring
            If Len(substring) > 0 Then  ' ignore empty substrings

                If Not dict.Exists(substring) Then dict(substring) = 0
                dict(substring) = dict(substring) + 1
                
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print key, dict(key) ' prints the name, and the number of times
Next
```

(My original approach didn't take into account that a given cell might have more than one name in it.)

Answer (score 0):

Using two tables - `Table1` and `Table2` as show in columns B & D below.
[image]

First join both tables together with a comma separated delimiter:
`TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Table1[Name],Table2[Name])`

Then swap the commas for XML tags:
`SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Table1[Name],Table2[Name]),",","</s><s>")`

Use `FILTERXML` to produce a list of all values (shown in **F3:F12**):
`=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Table1[Name],Table2[Name]),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")`

Create a unique list of these values (shown in **H3:H6**):
`=UNIQUE(F3#)`

Count the values (shown in **I3:I6**):
`=COUNTIF(F3#,H3#)`

**Edit:**
Using your table and column names:
`=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Running[With],Cycling[With]),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I just implemented it and it works a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A small additional question, hope you can help. I now have a spilled list of values, but can I in someway make it into a (dynamic) table. This way I could also sort for most occurences and such. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can reference the spilled range (using the values in `H3:I6` in my picture above as an example) using `H3#`.  You can reference the first column using `=INDEX(H3#,,1)` and the second using `=INDEX(H3#,,2)`.